# Feature Engineering Encoding for multiple category with huge category range

Tags: python, feature-engineering, feature-extraction, encoding

I need to encode a column "Tags" that has a total of 144 different types and at the same time a row can contain multiple tags. What's the best encoding method in this situation?

One-hot Encoding would be computationally expensive.

Binary Encoding only works if a row contains 1 tag (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I think it depends of the problem you want to solve. Have you considered using label encoding, for example to compute the mean target per tag ? 

Module category_encoder may be useful : https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders

Comment: Or could you tell us about your use-case ?

Comment: @Theudbald
Thanks for your reply. My first goal is to find what are the common features of a successful cryptocurrency. And the "Tags" is one of the features.
Example: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/augur has 5 tags (of a total of 144 diff tags)